# OpenCV - can't draw long line

Tags: c++, opencv, drawing, line

I use OpenCV 2.4.5. I want to draw the lines between matched points of two images. The code is:

```
const int &w=image1.cols;
for (size_t i = 0; i<good_matches.size(); i++ )
{
    //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
    img1.push_back(keypoints1[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
    img2.push_back(keypoints2[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);

    circle(image1,img1[i],20,Scalar(255,0,0),5);
    circle(image2,img2[i],20,Scalar(0,255,0),5);

    line(image1,img1[i],Point2f(img2[i].x+w,img2[i].y),Scalar(255,255,255),5);
    line(image2,Point2f(img1[i].x-w,img1[i].y),img2[i],Scalar(255,255,255),5);
}
```

When length of line `within the bounds of image` is more than `16400` I get strange result. It looks like triangle of lines or sometimes broken line between 2 corresponding points instead of straigth line between points.

So I should to draw line segments instead of total line. But it's not very convenient. Is it due to restrictions of line drawing algorythm or can be correcteed somehow?

Comment: Perhaps you can use a built in function `drawMatches`. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/drawing_function_of_keypoints_and_matches.html?highlight=drawmatches#void drawMatches(const Mat& img1, const vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints1, const Mat& img2, const vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints2, const vector<DMatch>& matches1to2, Mat& outImg, const Scalar& matchColor, const Scalar& singlePointColor, const vector<char>& matchesMask, int flags)

Comment: Alex,Thanks for prompting about `drawMatches` it will be useful for me in some other cases. But I tried it and result was the same because this function also try to draw full length of long line with line function that doesn't work in mine case.

Answer (score 0):

The line drawing function cannot draw very long lines.

Below is some code demonstrating that a line 32800 pixels long won't render, while a line 32700 pixels long will. The cv::line function breaks down inside a called function ThickLine (drawing.cpp).

```
int length = 32800;
cv::Mat canvas = cv::Mat::zeros(5,length,CV_8UC3);// create blank canvas
cv::line(canvas,cv::Point(0,1),cv::Point(length,1),cv::Scalar(255,0,0),1,8); //blue line
cv::line(canvas,cv::Point(0,3),cv::Point(length-100,3),cv::Scalar(0,0,255),1,8); //red line
cv::imwrite("d:\\canvas.tif",canvas);
```

I don't know why your lines corrupt over 16400 (maybe 2^14 ?) pixels in length. You could try setting the thickness to 1, which leads down a different code path and see what happens.